# Android `templateMergeStrategy` in strings.xml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

**What does the `templateMergeStrategy` property mean in an Android resource?**

e.g. in Google Maps API key file

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    AIza.......some...secret...key...
</string>
```

---

I would have expected a simple google (or duckduckgo) search to give me results, but unfortunately it only seems to give me Google Maps API questions.

Unfortunately the [Android Developer Docs on "String Resources"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) are also lacking in that department.

Answer (score 4):

From [change log](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/545bef4%5E!/)

> Uses this to overwrite the instructions in the Google Maps template.
>   Subsequent runs of the template always update the instructions with
>   the user's current keystore credentials.
>
> Also changed the Maps instructions to deep link into a Google
>   developer console flow, which allows for easier key generation.

Comment: I also found that. Any idea what it means?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier No. I have no idea about that. This is completely new to me and going to look into it.

Answer (score 3):

It means Android Studio template engine will preserve this line when a new Google Maps Activity is created, so you don't loose your key.

Comment: Why would the line not be preserved otherwise? Are the keys not issued based on the applications package name?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the following in [Google Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/545bef4%5E!/)

Following commit in Google code states

> Uses this to overwrite the instructions in the Google Maps template.
>   Subsequent runs of the template always update the instructions with
>   the user's current keystore credentials.

Comment: As per my question to @Pankaj... Any idea what this means?

Comment: No idea. I will look further into this.

Comment: It seems that they recently added this attribute into the system, as I am not able to put this attribute into prior lollipop.

Comment: Maybe that is why there is so little documentation on it.