# What is "templateMergeStrategy" attribute in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

When creating a new **Google Maps Activity** in Android Studio, it creates both of the class and the XML file related to the above created activity in addition to a **google_maps_api.xml** file to add our **API key**.
Inside the **google_maps_api.xml** I don't understand what is the **templateMergeStrategy="preserve"** attribute inside the following string tag:

`<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_API_KEY</string>`

Referring to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820121/android-templatemergestrategy-in-strings-xml) I didn't find a clarified solution